# Matrix presentation of cubic form and quartic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

When I was studying my engineering degree, I learn from Linear Algebra about the quadratic form of ${x^T}Ax$. Therefore, I am just having simple academic curiosity regarding the presentation of order 3 and order 4 polynomials.

Does matrix presentation of cubic form and quartic form even exist and how do they look like?

Thank you for your enthusiasm!

Comment: Unfortunately cubic and quartic forms are *really* a thing, as they become very complicated. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430365/there-is-a-nice-theory-of-quadratic-forms-how-about-cubic-forms-quartic-forms

Comment: This is quite sad since some engineer applications that I have been working on have started to manifest themself as optimization of cubic form over some linear constraint. :(

Comment: Well don't trust me too much. I'm just one guy who hasn't really encountered them. It's possible they have some nice theory, at least under certain conditions.

Comment: I don't know of a matrix representation but quite obviously when we write the vector $x$ as $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and use a bunch of tensor components $A_{i_1,\dots,i_p}$ of order $p$ we have a $p$-th order form by
$$
\sum_{i_1,\dots, i_p=1}^n A_{i_1,\dots,i_p} x_{i_1}\dots x_{i_p}
$$
which is nothing else than a homogeneous polynomial of degree $p$ in the variables
$x_1,\dots,x_n\,.$

Comment: This is the domain of tensor calculus.